# Normalize.css top header gap

Tags: css, html

I'm starting a new project and i wanna use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) but i'm facing one little problem with. In the top of the DOM you'll find a yellow gap, body background-color.
The main container is green colored and contains exactly the html from normalize.css demo.

You'll find a demo right here: http://goo.gl/hf8cv

Comment: Is the problem the yellow gap (in which case delete body{background-color:yellow})? Or displaying the default HTML?

Comment: This file will be used in iframe and there's too much space in the top.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you see is margin collapsing.

When an element with a margin is inside an element without border or padding, the margin collapses with the margin of the parent element.

It's the margin of the `h1` element that you see at the top. As none of the parents have border or padding, the margin collapses all the way out to the outermost container.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!! h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{margin:0;padding:0} solve the problem, for the moment. Is there any another way to solve these collapses without affecting margin on headings (h1,h2 ...)?

Comment: Adding `overflow:auto` on the parent also keeps the margins from collapsing.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` for the main `div` element will overlap the content fully.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Why would you want margins to collapse?

Comment: @MattiasNordqvist: That's just one of those things; it's only when you consider the alternatives that you realise that it's the only sound alternative. If you want margins they have to collapse, otherwise you don't have margins, you only have another padding outside the element.